# Choose colors in GXT Pie chart

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, gxt-charts

I am using GXT (pro) charts. I try ot draw a donut which show the distribution of object statuses.

Let's take 3 statuses :

- OK : I want it to appear in green
- KO : I want it to appear in red
- Cancelled : I want it to appear in blue

Let's take this dataModel :

```
public class DataModel {

  private Status status;
  private Long count;

  public DataModel(Status status, Long count) {
    this.status = status;
    this.count = count;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return status.name();
  }

  public String getName() {
    return status.name()
  }

  public Long getData() {
    return rapportAvancement.getCount();
  }

}
```

Here is how I set the colors :

```
public static final String[] COLORS_STR
 = new String[]{"#24b324", "#247bb3", "#b32424"};

[...]

for (Status status : Status.values()) {
  Gradient slice = new Gradient(status.name(), 0);
  slice.setId(status.name());
  slice.setColor(COLORS_STR[status.ordinal()]);
  chart.addGradient(slice);
  series.addColor(slice);
}
```

The result is fine :

[image: Chart-ok]

But if I there are only 2 zones, the colors are shifted (KO appears in blue instead of red):

[image]

Is there an option that allows to assign colors based on criteria instead of assigning them in sequence?

Comment: whether the status is restricted to 3 or can it be more??
and also may i know what does the `status.ordinal()` return

Comment: @Holla Yes. I restricted to 3 for the readability of the question but I have the same problem with more colors.

Comment: please answer my complete question "may i know what does the `status.ordinal()` return"

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the API and it doesn't appear to be possible.  Could you just avoid adding any statuses that don't have any data when you iterate through the statuses to create the slices?